# String could not be parsed as XML - PHP

Tags: php, json, xml, parsing, curl

I am trying to get response from a web service but i am getting this error, I have googled it but found nothing.

ERROR :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: String could not be parsed as XML

I am using CURL to get file contents, here is my code :

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,"URL_ADDRESS");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

$json = new SimpleXMLElement($query);
$json1 = json_decode($json, true);

echo $json1;
```

I am using this same method for some other service and it worked fine there, but I am getting error for this service.

Response of web service is :

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
[{"booking_id":161280112,"sender_name":"MR IRFAN","receiver_name":"MR TAHIR","DT":"Sep 21 2016 11:53AM","STC":"MULTAN - NAWAN SHEHR","DTC":"CHOWK BAHADURPUR - RAHIM YAR KHAN"}]
</string>
( function(){ window.SIG_EXT = {}; } )()
```

ANY IDEA, what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Is "( function(){ window.SIG_EXT = {}; } )()" part of what you pass to new SimpleXMLElement? Because this may destroy the validity of the xml.

Comment: @Blackbam The other service which i successfully parsed also contains this, so i think this doesn't matter

Comment: I think it matters because you must have valid XML otherwise the PHP parser might complain. From <string> ... to ... </string> it is valid xml